# spread then subtract consecutive rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I have a data frame where I need to pair consecutive events within the same day and subtract the later from the former. Each has a timestamp and a date.

```
         time                     date   event   score
0 2022-03-07 06:45:00+00:00  2022-03-07  light   80.066667
1 2022-03-07 18:12:00+00:00  2022-03-07  dark   79.857667
2 2022-03-30 06:25:00+00:00  2022-03-30  light  107.060833
3 2022-03-30 13:38:00+00:00  2022-03-30  dark  105.324000
4 2022-03-30 13:40:00+00:00  2022-03-30  dark  105.239750
5 2022-03-30 15:47:00+00:00  2022-03-30  light  106.863143
6 2022-04-01 06:25:00+00:00  2022-04-01  light  101.271867
```

I have tried spreading the data frame using

```
df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='event', values='score')

event                             light       dark
time                                             
2022-03-07 06:45:00+00:00   80.066667         NaN
2022-03-07 18:12:00+00:00         NaN   79.857667
2022-03-30 06:25:00+00:00  107.060833         NaN
2022-03-30 13:38:00+00:00         NaN  105.324000
2022-03-30 13:40:00+00:00         NaN  105.239750
2022-03-30 15:47:00+00:00  106.863143         NaN
2022-04-01 06:25:00+00:00  101.271867         NaN
```

however because the events happen at different times the spread data frame has NaNs. I would ideally end up with this, where I keep the time of the first occurrence in the pair (light or dark), align the events (note: corresponding dark to match light as not yet occurred for 2022-04-01) and when light comes first I subtract the later value from the former and when dark comes first I subtract the former value from the later.

```
event                             light  dark          diff
time                                             
2022-03-07 06:45:00+00:00   80.066667    79.857667    -0.208999
2022-03-30 06:25:00+00:00  107.060833    105.324000   -1.7368
2022-03-30 13:40:00+00:00  106.863143    105.239750   -1.6233
2022-04-01 06:25:00+00:00  101.271867    NaN          NaN
```

Comment: for `diff`, `-1.6233` should be `1.6233` right? because dark comes before light?

Comment: value was correct, text was wrong. -1.6233 is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `groupby` + `cumcount` to create groups, then use that groups in `groupby` + `first` to get the first time each event happens each day. Then `pivot`.

Finally, use `diff` to get the difference between "light" and "dark" and `assign` the differences to column "diff" in `df`:

```
out = (df.assign(time=df.groupby(df.groupby('event').cumcount())['time'].transform('first'))
       .pivot('time', 'event', 'score').reset_index().rename_axis([None], axis=1)
       .assign(diff=lambda x: x['dark']-x['light']))
```

Output:

```
                        time        dark       light      diff
0  2022-03-07 06:45:00+00:00   79.857667   80.066667 -0.209000
1  2022-03-30 06:25:00+00:00  105.324000  107.060833 -1.736833
2  2022-03-30 13:40:00+00:00  105.239750  106.863143 -1.623393
3  2022-04-01 06:25:00+00:00         NaN  101.271867       NaN
```

Comment: is there a way of doing the subtraction within the transformation? I need to always subtract the later from the former and in the out table I cannot identify whether light or dark came first in order to carry out the subtraction

Comment: @DaveTheRave do you mean to subtract light from dark? could you edit your question with an example?

Comment: I have edited the question. Apologies about the lack of specificity originally. Its a slightly more difficult problem.

Comment: @DaveTheRave edited the answer, see if it does it.

Comment: yes I think that does it. Ive edited the question again to be consistent with the original logic. I will test on a few more cases to see if this solution is general - i.e. diff=lambda x: x['dark']-x['light'] is consistent with "when light comes first I subtract the later value from the former and when dark comes first I subtract the former value from the later"